# Why difference between pointers to two consecutive array entries is always 1, if not cast to char pointer?

Tags: c

What is the point of typecasting into char ? Why not typecast it in int instead ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[15];
    arr[1]=5;
    arr[0]=2;
    int diff = (char *)&arr[1] - (char *)&arr[0];
    int diff2 = &arr[1] - &arr[0];
    printf("%d\n%d", diff, diff2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the code you show? Where does it come from? Try to turn this into less of a guessing game please.

Comment: For determining the size of an entry in an array, the widely spread idiom is `sizeof(arr[0])`. Do you know why that is not used?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes because I am trying to find the size of any data type without using sizeof operator, here I used integer array to find the size of int.

Comment: Why do you want to find the **size of** anything without using the operator `sizeof` ?

Comment: This is related to the equivalence of using pointer syntax and array syntax.   Subtracting two pointers always give a number of elements.   So, if `p1` points at `arr[i]` and `p2` points at `arr[j]`, then `p1 - p2 == i - j`.    It doesn't matter if `arr` is an array of `char`, or an array of some massive data structure.   Typecasting to `char` before doing the subtraction does things in terms of bytes.   So `(char *)&arr[1] - (char *)&arr[0] == (1-0)*sizeof(arr[0])`   i.e. the size of an element in bytes.

Comment: @Peter Would you like to turn that into an answer and maybe highlight the difference to mine? Especially the difference to mine I do not really get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is not for the weak of heart, but always this will be true:

```
(&arr[0]/* pointer to first element*/)
+
(1 /* "next" */)
==
(&arr[1]/* pointer to second element*/)
```

**This is true for any `type`**, it is part of the rules of pointer arithmetic.
So it cannot be any other than

```
(&arr[1]/* pointer to second element */)
-
(&arr[0]/* pointer to first element  */)
==
1
```

which is of course exactly like

```
diff2 == 1
```

This is not changed if the result of `&` is cast to a pointer to the actual type of the array entries, in this case `int` and `int*`. With that `+1` still means "next array entry".

On the other hand

```
(char *)&arr[0]
```

is bend to be a pointer to something different than the type of the entries of the array. It has been forced to be a pointer to a char. If you increase that by one, it has to be a pointer to the next char and

```
(char *)&arr[0] + N
==
(char *)&arr[1]
```

can only be true, if N is the number of chars between the addresses of two consecutive array entries.
So

```
N =
(char *)&arr[1] - (char *)&arr[0]
```

ensures it.

Comment: Okay but why do we need to type cast in charge * why not int *

Comment: I refer explicitly to "why not `int*`?" now. Is it clear now?

Comment: Good explanation. **"This is true for any `type`"** should be highlighted. As the `type` is what controls the number of bytes used as the offset of each element from the previous for pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the input, which I incorporated. I guess I am a little shy with using bold etc.

Comment: It's not something that you just splatter through the answer like paint, but for fundamental concepts, it helps to cement the point (`type - controls pointer arithmetic`)

Answer (score 2):

To understand this let us take a simple example:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[3]={1,2,3};
    int *p=arr;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d ",*p);
        p++; // In this line p is an address. 
             //Here address is incremented by 1.

        // But the logic is that 1 is an integer. 
        // If 1 might not be an integer then the result should not be like this. 
        // Same is in your case if you are storing difference of two addresses
        // in an integer then it calculates the difference
        // with respect to the type of address(int in your case). 

    }
    return 0;
}
```

In c++ if integer is used with addresses for any operation then its calculations are totally based upon the type of address(int,void,float....).